# set a custom button selector bitmap item from SVG

Tags: android, button, svg, bitmap

I have a customization for a standard Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true">
   <layer-list>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/standard_button_normal_background_layer1"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/standard_button_normal_background_layer0"/>
     <item><bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/the_bitmap" /></item>
   </layer-list>
 </item>

...

</selector>
```

I need to change the bitmap with the one I load from an SVG file. I use

http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

that can produce a PictureDrawable:

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.icon);
PictureDrawable pd = svg.createPictureDrawable();
imageView.setImageDrawable(pd);
```

How can I access the specific `<bitmap>` item, and how can I set the bitmap? Any solution?

**EDIT:**

I want to know if I can programmatically add to the Button customization a picture on the bottom of the `<layer-list>` items. Picture come from svg, so it's not on the compiled resource.

The result I need is a button with some custom graphic (defined by `<layer-list>`) and a icon centered inside it coming from svg.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to write an XML file that references the Picture that you loaded from an SVG, that's sort of a chicken and an egg. When your app is deployed, all the stuff in res/ is read-only. So by dynamically loading a bitmap from a set of drawing instructions you can simply store the outputed bitmap.

`imageView.onDraw(mBitmapCanvas);`

That's all you can do. You could create a raster as a prebuild step but you will lose the size benefits of the vector being bundled with your app.

If you are asking how to edit the layout-list, try this:

**layer-list.xml**

```
<layer-list>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/standard_button_normal_background_layer1"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/standard_button_normal_background_layer0"/>
     <!-- Remove bitmap -->
</layer-list>
```

Then when you want to use this drawable:

```
LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layout_list);
ArrayList<Drawable> layers = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
for(int i=0; i < drawable.getNumberOfLayers(); i++) {
   layers.add(drawable.getDrawable(i);
}

layers.add(new BitmapDrawable(mBitmap));
drawable = new LayerDrawable(layers.toArray(new Drawable[layers.size()]);
```

Comment: Ok I see your answer update. The layer-List is inside a <selector> but I think I'll discover how acces it. So, you say I need a BitmapDrawable. I can prepare it in run-time from SVG:

`PictureDrawable pd = svg.createPictureDrawable();`
`Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);`
`Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);`
`canvas.drawPicture(pd.getPicture());`

Comment: yeah you can organize the selector however you want, you can even reference other files within a selector. As for the rest of the code here I think that would be how you get the bitmap you wanted. You do need to wrap it in a drawable for the layerlist to work. You could even use a PictureDrawable.